# Windows 8 bootloader doesn't pick up Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, bootloader

After installing Windows 8, its booloader picked up my Linux partition but it didn't pick up my Windows 7 partition on a separate disk.

I've looked in the Windows 8 bootloader options and advanced options but could not find how.

Have I overlooked some Windows 8 features or should I consider a tool like EasyBCD?